# Get a called functions list in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, `get_included_files()` returns an array with the names of included files.

In a similar fashion, is there any way to get an array with the names of called functions with parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to achieve what you want and finally came up with an reasonable solution.

Make a class named `Debug` and include that above every file you want to debug in. Build yourself a function that prints nicely the information stored in `$calls`.

```
class Debug {
    private static $calls;

    public static function log($message = null)
    {
        if(!is_array(self::$calls))
            self::$calls = array();

        $call = debug_backtrace(false);
        $call = (isset($call[1]))?$call[1]:$call[0];

        $call['message'] = $message;
        array_push(self::$calls, $call);
    }
}
```

Call this function everytime you declare a function first line in the functionbody: `Debug::log($message(optional) )`

Answer (score 9):

> In this way, Is any way to get an array with the names of called functions with parameters?

No.

What you can do is a [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) which will show all the function calls (with parameters) that lead to the execution of *the line you are doing the backtrace from* (the "call stack"), but that's different from all functions that were ever called in the script.

What do you want to do? Maybe there's a different approach.

Comment: @Ozzone for workaround solutions you would have to be more verbose - what is the nature of the problem, how getting a list of all functions would help, etc. Maybe what you need is an actual debugger?

Answer (score 6):

I was searching for something similar and found xdebug's tracing very useful.

Here's an example of how it could look like:
http://devzone.zend.com/1135/tracing-php-applications-with-xdebug/

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware.

You can however use [debug_backtrace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to get the currently active function/method hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do what you want. Sorry.

The closest I can get is the [`function_exists()`](http://uk.php.net/function_exists) function, which will tell you whether a specific function has been loaded.

What exactly do you want to achieve here? I can't see a use case (outside of a php_info() type screen) that would require a list of available functions.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install it as an extension, but a profiler like [XHProf](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html) will give you a breakdown of which functions are called and how long they take, as well as a callgraph.

Answer (score 1):

[XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) or [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind/wiki)/[KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/) will show you the functions called, but not their parameters.

You could also use [get_defined_functions](http://php.net/get_defined_functions), which gives you a list of all functions defined. But it won't show you which functions have actually been called, and with what parameters.

If you really need to know the parameters, I don't know of any tools other than a custom logger like the one Henze provided in his answer.